# Angular2: How to bind the mouse hover & out events for dynamically created the html string; Also, how to get those element?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Here is the scenario:

In child component, I have added some html content as a string conditionally. I want to bind the hover & out events for those elements and get into the parent component func while mouse hover & out.

```
ChildComponent{

...
someFunc(){
....
htmlDynamicContent = `<div (mouseover)="changeStyle($event)" 
(mouseout)="changeStyle($event)”>Test</div>`
...
return htmlDynamicContent;
}
}

ParentComponent{

changeStyle (event){
//Change element styles
}

}
```

Much apperciate your help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

add an event emitter to the child component:

```
@Output() onChangeStyle = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

emit it on hover/out:

```
<div (mouseover)="onChangeStyle.emit($event)" 
(mouseout)="onChangeStyle.emit($event)”>Test</div>
```

then bind to the EventEmitter in the parent:

```
<child (onChangeStyle)="changeStyle($event)"><child>
```